# I wasn't able to use the get['id'] on header[Location...]

Tags: php, html, mysql

Why can I use this to pass the id

```
<a href='detail.php?id=".$row['posts_id'].
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts_id=".$_GET['id'];
```

But not on this which gives me a blank id

```
header("Location: ../detail.php?id=".$_GET['id']);
```

Comment: This is a lot of code - are you sure all of them are relevant to the question?

Comment: I'm sorry if it bugs you. I just wanted to explain it without leaving any important details(minor too). Peace, @Qirel

Comment: The question should contain just enough code to reproduce the issue, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I get that you don't want to leave any details out, but too much code would be too much. What exactly happens, why isn't it working? Do you get any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: Is that so? I'm very sorry. I'm still a tumbleweed. There's no errors, just this warning (
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\includes\questionsdetail.inc.php on line 5)

Comment: This is line 5 --> $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result); This always shows up when there's no id in the url.

Comment: What's the output of `echo mysqli_error($conn);` there? The query clearly failed, so you need to figure out why, and using `mysqli_error()` will get you the error-message :-)

Comment: i am able to run the query(insert comment) but not display the id on the url. I have edited my old question, the header(location) might be the culprit since if I manually put the id on the url, it runs perfectly

Comment: Check the mysql-error none the less, if you get a warning, it means the query failed. But what's the output from `var_dump($_GET['id']);` where the header-call fails?

Comment: I used this code echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn)); under mysqli_query and removed header. It did not display any errors.